# how to update the progress bar from tasks running concurrently

Tags: c#, progress-bar, task-parallel-library

I am try to bind parallel task to a listView that contains pprogressBars.
I am using a limited scheduler that only allows specified maximum of parallel degree.
So far it works OK most of the time but occasionally two tasks updates the same progress bar in the listView.
Below is my code.

Any idea how to prevent two tasks from updating the same progressbar in the listView? 
Or how to update the progress bar from tasks running concurrently?

```
public class MyClass
{
  public ObservableCollection<StatusInfo> StatusItems { get; set; }
  private Object thisLock = new Object();

  public int Process() //handled
  {
    StatusItems = new ObservableCollection<StatusInfo>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)  // initialize progress bar collection
    {
      StatusInfo sInfo = new StatusInfo();
      sInfo.ThreadID = i;
      sInfo.Table = "No Table";
      sInfo.Percentage = 0;
      sInfo.Status = AppInfo.AVAILABLE;
      sInfo.Minimum = 0;
      sInfo.Maximum = 100;
      sInfo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      StatusItems.Add(sInfo);
    }
    Parent.StatusItems = StatusItems; // assign to viewmodel

    int numberOfBackGroundThread = 4;
    LimitedTaskScheduler scheduler = new LimitedTaskScheduler(numberOfBackGroundThread);
    TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(scheduler);
    var ui = LimitedTaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    Task[] tasks = new Task[rows.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
    {
      ......
      tasks[i] = factory.StartNew<string>(() =>
      {
        int barIndex = -1;
        int threadID = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        cnt++;
        if (cnt > numberOfBackGroundThread - 1)
        {
          while (true)
          {                 
            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfBackGroundThread; j++)
            {
              lock (thisLock)
              {
                if (StatusItems[j].Status == "AVAILABLE" || StatusItems[j].Status == "DONE") 
                {
                  //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Current table = {0}, Cuurent table type = {1}, BarIndex = {2}, ThreadID = {3}, Prev TableName = {4}, Prev TableType = {5}, Prev Status = {6} PrevThreadID = {7}", tabName, tabType, j.ToString(), Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString(), StatusItems[j].Table, StatusItems[j].TabType, StatusItems[j].Status, StatusItems[j].ThreadID));
                  // 0. Assign the current task to a display slot StatusItems[j] that is currently free.
                  // 1. We lock this piece of code to prevent another concurrent task from picking the same slot.
                  // 2. And we update the slot as "Occupied" immediately to avoid to prevent another concurrent task from picking the same slot.
                  // 3. We also add one extra slot to avoid concurrent tasks competing on the same sidplay slot and reduce wait on the lock.
                  // All of the above cannot completely avoid two thread using the same display slot. We may need a new way to 
                  // 4. Since multiple tasks may run on the same thread we may see the same thread ID appear on different display slots.
                  StatusItems[j].Status = "Occupied";
                  barIndex = j;
                  break; // break for loop
                }
              }
            }
            if (barIndex >= 0) { break; }  // break while loop
          }
        }
        else { barIndex = cnt; }

        StatusItems[barIndex].TabType = tabType;
        StatusItems[barIndex].ThreadID = threadID;

        int nStatus = IndividualProcess(barIndex);
        if (nStatus < 0) { AppInfo.JobStatus = "01"; }
        return result;
      });
    }
    var done = factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, completedTasks => { AppInfo.Finished = true; });
    done.ContinueWith(completedTasks => { int nStatus = PostProcess(); }, ui);
    return returnStatus;
  }

  private int IndividualProcess(int barIndex)
  {
     for (int i=0; i< 100; i++)  
     {
       perform work...
       SetProgressbar (i, StatusItems, barIndex, "in progress")
     }
     SetProgressbar (100, StatusItems, barIndex, "DONE")
  } 

  public void SetProgressbar(int pPercent, ObservableCollection<StatusInfo> pInfo, int pInfoIndex, string pStatus)
  {
    try // Increment percentage for COPY or nested PURGE 
    {
      if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread != System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread)
      {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
          ((StatusInfo)pInfo[pInfoIndex]).Percentage = pPercent;
          ((StatusInfo)pInfo[pInfoIndex]).Status = pStatus; 
          ((StatusInfo)pInfo[pInfoIndex]).PCT = pPercent.ToString() + "%";
        }));
      }
      else // When the current thread is main UI thread. The label won't be updated until the EntityCopy() finishes.
      {
        ((StatusInfo)pInfo[pInfoIndex]).Percentage = pPercent;
        ((StatusInfo)pInfo[pInfoIndex]).Status = pStatus; 
        ((StatusInfo)pInfo[pInfoIndex]).PCT = pPercent.ToString() + "%";
      }
    }
    catch { throw; }
  }      
}

public class LimitedTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
{
  // Fields
  // Whether the current thread is processing work items.
  [ThreadStatic]
  private static bool _currentThreadIsProcessingItems;
  // The list of tasks to be executed. 
  private readonly LinkedList<Task> _tasks = new LinkedList<Task>(); // protected by lock(_tasks) 
  /// <summary>The maximum concurrency level allowed by this scheduler.</summary> 
  private readonly int _maxDegreeOfParallelism;
  /// <summary>Whether the scheduler is currently processing work items.</summary> 
  private int _delegatesQueuedOrRunning = 0; // protected by lock(_tasks) 

  /// <summary> 
  /// Initializes an instance of the LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler class with the 
  /// specified degree of parallelism. 
  /// </summary> 
  /// <param name="maxDegreeOfParallelism">The maximum degree of parallelism provided by this scheduler.</param>
  public LimitedTaskScheduler(int maxDegreeOfParallelism)
  {
      if (maxDegreeOfParallelism < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxDegreeOfParallelism");
      _maxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism;
  }

  /// <summary>Queues a task to the scheduler.</summary> 
  /// <param name="task">The task to be queued.</param>
  protected sealed override void QueueTask(Task task)
  {
      // Add the task to the list of tasks to be processed.  If there aren't enough 
      // delegates currently queued or running to process tasks, schedule another. 
    lock (_tasks)
      {
          _tasks.AddLast(task);
          if (_delegatesQueuedOrRunning < _maxDegreeOfParallelism)
          {
              ++_delegatesQueuedOrRunning;
              NotifyThreadPoolOfPendingWork();
          }
      }
  }

  /// <summary> 
  /// Informs the ThreadPool that there's work to be executed for this scheduler. 
  /// </summary> 
  private void NotifyThreadPoolOfPendingWork()
  {
      ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
      {
          // Note that the current thread is now processing work items. 
          // This is necessary to enable inlining of tasks into this thread.
          _currentThreadIsProcessingItems = true;
          try
          {
              // Process all available items in the queue. 
              while (true)
              {
                  Task item;
                  lock (_tasks)
                  {
                      // When there are no more items to be processed, 
                      // note that we're done processing, and get out. 
                      if (_tasks.Count == 0)
                      {
                          --_delegatesQueuedOrRunning;
                          break;
                      }

                      // Get the next item from the queue
                      item = _tasks.First.Value;
                      _tasks.RemoveFirst();
                  }

                  // Execute the task we pulled out of the queue 
                  base.TryExecuteTask(item);
              }
          }
          // We're done processing items on the current thread 
          finally { _currentThreadIsProcessingItems = false; }
      }, null);
  }

  /// <summary>Attempts to execute the specified task on the current thread.</summary> 
  /// <param name="task">The task to be executed.</param>
  /// <param name="taskWasPreviouslyQueued"></param>
  /// <returns>Whether the task could be executed on the current thread.</returns> 
  protected sealed override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
  {
      // If this thread isn't already processing a task, we don't support inlining 
      if (!_currentThreadIsProcessingItems) return false;

      // If the task was previously queued, remove it from the queue 
      if (taskWasPreviouslyQueued) TryDequeue(task);

      // Try to run the task. 
      return base.TryExecuteTask(task);
  }

  /// <summary>Attempts to remove a previously scheduled task from the scheduler.</summary> 
  /// <param name="task">The task to be removed.</param>
  /// <returns>Whether the task could be found and removed.</returns> 
  protected sealed override bool TryDequeue(Task task)
  {
      lock (_tasks) return _tasks.Remove(task);
  }

  /// <summary>Gets the maximum concurrency level supported by this scheduler.</summary> 
  public sealed override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel { get { return _maxDegreeOfParallelism; } }

  /// <summary>Gets an enumerable of the tasks currently scheduled on this scheduler.</summary> 
  /// <returns>An enumerable of the tasks currently scheduled.</returns> 
  protected sealed override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
  {
      bool lockTaken = false;
      try
      {
          Monitor.TryEnter(_tasks, ref lockTaken);
          if (lockTaken) return _tasks.ToArray();
          else throw new NotSupportedException();
      }
      finally
      {
          if (lockTaken) Monitor.Exit(_tasks);
      }
  }
}
```

Update: 
Task scheduler may not be relevant. I put it here just in case someone could find something new that I never thought of doing or missing.

Comment: I can't see why task scheduler is relevant to this question. Can it be rephrased like "how to update the progress bar from tasks running concurrently", regardless of the task task scheduler?

Comment: this doesn't look like MVVM code and in fact if you adopt MVVM  you don't have this question.

Comment: did you _get final solution_ using `SemaphoreSlim` ? Would love to see the full example. Why ***only 4 progressbars***, not more ? ***500 tasks always*** ? –

Comment: At any given time there are only 4 tasks running concurrently due to the limited scheduler ? why 4 for limited scheduler '

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Any idea how to prevent two tasks to update the same progressbar in
>   the listView? Or how to update the progress bar from tasks running
>   concurrently?

If you have more than one task running in parallel, and you really want to **show the progress of *each* individual task** to the user, you'd need to show a *separate* progress bar for *each* task.

How you'd do it depends on the UI structure. E.g., if you have a listview where each item is a task, you can add a progress bar as a child window for each listview item:

[image: Listview with progress bar]

This may be an overkill though, usually it's enough to have a single progress bar to track the overall progress. I.e., if you have a 100 tasks, your progress bar will show 100% when all 100 tasks have completed.

Note although, that task #50 (e.g.) may become completed before the task #45, so you can't use the task's number to update the progress. To show the progress correctly, you'd count completed tasks, and use that counter as the progress indicator.

**Updated** to address the comment:

> I have 4 progressbars in the listview and 500 tasks. At any given time
>   there are only 4 tasks running concurrently due to the limited
>   scheduler. I try to assign a progress bar in the listview with free
>   status to a new incoming task and then set the status of the
>   progressbar to free when the task is done so that the progressbar can
>   be reused by another new incoming task. Does that make sense? Or am I
>   going to a deadend?

I'm not sure it is a sensible UI design decision, but if you want it that way, you can use `SemaphoreSlim` to allocate a progress bar as a limited resource. Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TaskProgress
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await DoWorkAsync();
        }

        const int MAX_PARALLEL = 4;

        readonly object _lock = new Object();

        readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = 
            new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: MAX_PARALLEL);

        HashSet<Task> _pendingTasks;

        Queue<ProgressBar> _availableProgressBars;

        // do all Task
        async Task DoWorkAsync()
        {
            _availableProgressBars = new Queue<ProgressBar>();
            _pendingTasks = new HashSet<Task>();

            var progressBars = new ProgressBar[] { 
                this.progressBar1, 
                this.progressBar2, 
                this.progressBar3, 
                this.progressBar4 };

            foreach (var item in progressBars)
                _availableProgressBars.Enqueue(item);

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) // start 50 tasks
                QueueTaskAsync(DoTaskAsync());

            await Task.WhenAll(WithLock(() => _pendingTasks.ToArray()));
        }

        // do a sigle Task
        readonly Random _random = new Random(Environment.TickCount);

        async Task DoTaskAsync()
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                var progressBar = WithLock(() => _availableProgressBars.Dequeue());
                try
                {
                    progressBar.Maximum = 100;
                    progressBar.Value = 0;
                    IProgress<int> progress = 
                        new Progress<int>(value => progressBar.Value = value);

                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        // our simulated work takes no more than 10s
                        var sleepMs = _random.Next(10000) / 100;
                        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(sleepMs); // simulate work item
                            progress.Report(i);
                        }
                    });
                }
                finally
                {
                    WithLock(() => _availableProgressBars.Enqueue(progressBar));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphore.Release();
            }
        }

        // Add/remove a task to the list of pending tasks
        async void QueueTaskAsync(Task task)
        {
            WithLock(() => _pendingTasks.Add(task));
            try
            {
                await task;
            }
            catch
            {
                if (!task.IsCanceled && !task.IsFaulted)
                    throw;
                return;
            }
            WithLock(() => _pendingTasks.Remove(task));
        }

        // execute func inside a lock
        T WithLock<T>(Func<T> func)
        {
            lock (_lock)
                return func();
        }

        // execute action inside a lock
        void WithLock(Action action)
        {
            lock (_lock)
                action();
        }

    }
}
```

This code doesn't use a custom task scheduler, `SemaphoreSlim` is enough to limit the concurrency. Note also that protective locks (`WithLock`) are redundant here, because everything besides the `Task.Run` lambda runs the on UI thread. However, I decided to keep the locks as your application may have a different threading model. In this case, wherever you access `ProgressBar` or other UI, you should use `BeginInvoke` or like to do it on the UI thread.

Also, check ["Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx) for more details about `Progress<T>` pattern.

Comment: Hi, Noseratio, Thanks for the answer. In my listview each item is a progressbar. At the start of each task, I loop the list view to find a "free" progress bar and assign the progressbar/listview index to the the task. It works 95% of the time. But occasionally two tasks may use the same progress bar.Can you or anyone help find the wrong in my code?

Comment: @Shawn, I don't understand, do you *not* have a 1:1 mapping between tasks and the listview items?

Comment: No. I have 4 progressbars in the listview and 500 tasks. At any given time there are only 4 tasks running concurrently due to the limited scheduler. I try to assign a progress bar in the listview with free status to a new incoming task and then set the status of the progressbar to free when the task is done so that the progressbar can be reused by another new incoming task. Does that make sense? Or am I going to a deadend?

Comment: @Shawn, I'm not sure it is a sensible UI design, but if you want to stick with it, you'd better user `SemaphoreSlim` to allocate a progress bar as a limited resource. I'll post an example when time allows.

Comment: 4 progressbar in listview ? 500 tasks?

Comment: *At any given time there are only 4 tasks running concurrently due to the limited scheduler* Scheduler ? why 4 for limited scheduler ?

Comment: https://brianlagunas.com/does-reporting-progress-with-task-run-freeze-your-wpf-ui/ and Stephen Cleary witn Nito.AsyncEx https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/4248e50b4cb52b933c0d ObservableProgress in real world ?